# Pygame display module init and quit

Tags: python, pygame

Having a `pygame.display` window open, I call `pygame.display.quit()` upon it in order to destroy the window.
Because I need to open the window again, I call `pygame.display.init()` and `pygame.display.set_mode()`, but after these two functions are called, nothing happens.
Can anyone point me to the root of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code with a gui module...  Whenever you call `screen_off()` then the display quits.  Whenever you want display to come back, type everything you used before to turn it on.

If you want, use `pygame.display.quit()`, without it being inside the `screen_off()` function.  I suggest taking all the code you used to get the display on, and putting it into a function so you don't have to type it again to turn it on after it's been killed.

```
from pygame import *
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame, pygame.locals

from easygui import *

def screen_off():
    pygame.display.quit()

pygame.init()
canvas = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400),0,32)
red = (255,0,0)
canvas.fill(red)
pygame.display.update()
screen_off() #display is now OFF...


choice = ['Yes', 'No']
cc = buttonbox('Continue?', "Options", choice)
if cc == "Yes":
    #if you don't want to type these arguments below again to turn on the display then
    #put them into a function and call it
    pygame.init()
    canvas = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400),0,32)
    purple = (204,0,204)
    canvas.fill(purple)
    pygame.display.update()
    #display is now ON...
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
pygame.init()
```

so i asssume that:

```
pygame.quit()
```

works the same

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried calling just `pygame.quit()` or `pygame.init()`? I don't believe there is a `pygame.display.quit()`.

Comment: This answer is wrong. There _is_ a `pygame.display.quit`, plus this does not answer the OP's question.