# closing pygame windows without quitting

Tags: python, pygame, pyopengl

I open a pygame window and draw some stuff on it with pyopengl calls something like this:

```py
def run(facets, SCREEN_SIZE=(800, 600)):
  pygame.init()
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, HWSURFACE|OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF)

  glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_SIZE[0], SCREEN_SIZE[1])
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
  glLoadIdentity()
  gluPerspective(60.0, float(SCREEN_SIZE[0])/SCREEN_SIZE[1], .1, 1000.)
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
  glLoadIdentity()

  clock = pygame.time.Clock()

  glMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0))
  glMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))

  pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
  pygame.event.set_grab(True)

  while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        pygame.display.quit()
        print "returning..."
        return
      if event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
        pygame.quit()
        pygame.display.quit()
        print "returning..."
        return

    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    # Clear the screen, and z-buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    # other game loop code here, e.g. rendering the facets
    # and moving the viewport around.
```

I've left in pretty much all the pygame and pyopengl calls I make, in case any of them are relevant.

**what I want to happen:** to be running a session in bpython/IDLE/interactive python prompt, to call `run()` and look at something, hit `ESC` and have it close the window and return me to my prompt.

**what actually happens:** run my interactive session, build data structures, call `run()`, look at stuff, hit `ESC` and the window closes, but then immediately reopens. only way to get out is to kill the python process (which not only kills my interactive session, but in bpython leaves my shell window inoperable.) Note, I also *do* see the result of `print "returning..."` in the now defunct shell.

I've seen these questions:

- [Why does the pygame window not close properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694480/why-does-the-pygame-window-not-close-properly)
- [Pygame display module init and quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466411/pygame-display-module-init-and-quit)

But they only make me rather paranoid: is pygame really so resource-leaky that you have to *quit python* to get it to tidy up its mess?

Also, what dark magic is causing my `return` calls to *not return*?

Finally, can anyone tell me how to make this work the way I want? even utterly evil unsupported hacks are fine, for now, as I just need to debug my other code using this 3D renderer to see what I'm doing!

Comment: I believe IDLE has issues with certain things, like this. You may have better luck running from a command line, doing the same thing.

Comment: (the problem doesn't actually exist, see my answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: *always post all of your code!*

This was an indentation error in the calling code, which was calling `run()` over and over. `pygame` windows appear to be perfectly happy exiting to an interactive prompt.

I would also have seen this if I'd had the patience to press `ESC` 9 times.

Answer (score -1):

I always use

```
sys.exit()
```

just remember to import sys